# Are there any OSGi versions that are supported by Java 17?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, java-17

I have run an OSGi bundle with Java17 and got below at startup. Is OSGi not supported by Java 17 yet?

> org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.getServices()" is null

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Equinox? Eclipses site is confusing as usual so can't find anything about it but [release-notes](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-4.3.3/RELEASE-NOTES.md) for the latest Apache Karaf (4.3.3) seems to indicate that there's at least some level of support for Java 17 on Apache Felix.

Comment: Yes. I am using Eclipse Equinox. I will check on the release notes.

Comment: I am getting the same error in one of my projects. What is the solution you took? @UdeshAthukorala