# "org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.getServices()" is null with JDK 17

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, java-17

I have a project that runs fine in JDK 1.8 and 11. However, when I run the project in JDK 17, an osgi issue comes as shown below.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because the return value of "org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.getServices()" is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:174) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:76) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:92) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
```

I found the exact issue asked in [1] as well, but there were no solution.

[1] [Are there any OSGi versions that are supported by Java 17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475982/are-there-any-osgi-versions-that-are-supported-by-java-17)

Answer (score 0):

For me also same issue when i'm trying to run the JDK 18 and after that i used the 1.8 java version and it's started without any osg errors.

Seems it will support till jdk 11 as per the logs information.